# ClassNotFoundException & NoClassDefFoundError (Why??)

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, leap-motion, cytoscape

I want to make Cytoscape Simple App(It is like a Plug in Program).

So I should make a `.jar` file, and install it in Cytoscape Program.

My problem is the following:

I'll show you 2 cases.

> There are 6 classes(A,B,C,D,E,F), and 2 .jar file(that represent other
>   API)
>
> A (CytoscapeLeapMotionApp) is the main class(actually it doesn't include
>   main method, but it is the first class run when App is installed).
>
> C,E are classes that I made.
>
> B,D are in 1.jar.
>
> F(Listener) is in 2.jar(leap).

- Case 1

  A extends B

  C instance is created at A

  C extends D

  E instance is created at C

  E extends F

Result:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/leapmotion/leap/Listener     at
CytoscapeLeapMotionApp.<init>(CytoscapeLeapMotionApp.java:9)    ... 21
more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.leapmotion.leap.Listener    at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)   ... 22 more
```

- Case 2

  A extends B

  C instance is created at A

  C extends D

  F instance is created at C

Result:

Good, no errors!

Following is E extends F

```
public final class SampleListener extends Listener {
    //nothing
}
```

Comment: Try giving the full class name with namespace for Listener

Comment: How are you running the application? Within an IDE or via the command line?

Comment: @ray I'm Sorry, cause I'm a beginner, I don't know what namespace means. :(

Comment: @JamesB I make a .jar file that include above all classes.
And Start main Program(Cytoscape), install .jar file.

Comment: How do you run the jar file?

Comment: @ray I think you mean package, not namespace.

Comment: @JamesB I copy my .jar file in Cytoscape's App directory. Then it is intalled!

Comment: @DaeSungKim What is the structure of the jar file that you created?

Comment: lib META-INF A.class C.class E.class
In lib folder, there are 2.jar and some .dll file.
In META-INF, there is MANIFEST.MF file.

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException is also occured

Answer (score 0):

This error

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/leapmotion/leap/Listener at CytoscapeLeapMotionApp.(CytoscapeLeapMotionApp.java:9) ... 21 more

suggests that when CytoscapeLeapMotionApp is run, the type *com.leapmotion.leap.Listener* is not on the classpath.

You have indicated that this type is within a jar file named *2.jar* so this needs to be added to the classpath before you retry.

Comment: But when I try case 2, It also use class F(that is in 2.jar). But there are no errors. I don't know why this happen.

Comment: @DaeSungKim How are you running both cases?